# Scroll down change Text color not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My navbar have a title named LOGO ABCD,
I try to set when scrolling down change colour by adding and removing class,
but no idea why not work

LOGO ABCD

A

B

C

D

---

```
nav.navbar {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-top {
  background-color: Black;
}
nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-top a {
  color         : white;
}

nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-top a:hover {
  color     : yellow;
}
```

---

```
$(window).scroll(function(evt){
  if ($(window).scrollTop()>0)
    $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-top");
  else
    $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-top");
});
```

---

```
.PJ_title{color:grey;}
.PJ_color{color:red;}
```

---

```
$(window).scroll(function(evt){
  if ($(window).scrollTop()>300)
    $(".PJ_title").removeClass("PJ_color");
  else
    $(".PJ_title").addClass("PJ_color");
});
```

Comment: test this code: .PJ_color{color:red !important;}

Comment: tried before, not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test and "Test Title" has changed color successfully.

You can run lower snippet and scroll down and see change color. What's the problem?

```js
$(window).scroll(function(evt){
  if ($(window).scrollTop()>0)
    $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-top");
  else
    $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-top");
});
$(window).scroll(function(evt){
  if ($(window).scrollTop()>300)
    $(".PJ_title").removeClass("PJ_color");
  else
    $(".PJ_title").addClass("PJ_color");
});
```

```css
nav.navbar {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-top {
  background-color: Black;
}
nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-top a {
  color         : white;
}

nav.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-top a:hover {
  color     : yellow;
}
.PJ_title{color:grey;}
.PJ_color{color:red;}

.PJ_title{ position: fixed; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style='height: 1000px'>
<nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-top'>
  <a>Test</a>
</nav>
<h1 class='PJ_title'>Test Title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found it! my mistake to do that as below

    <p class="PJ_title PJ_color">LOGO ABCD</p>

Comment: But I don't know why, when I return to the top, the colour does not change back as yours

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do this. In the scroll function use, `this.scrollY`. Based on the value, add or remove classes as you see fit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function(evt) {
    var scrollPos = this.scrollY;
    if (scrollPos > 200) {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-green");
      $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-blue");
    } else {
      $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-green");
      $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-blue");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav.navbar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

nav.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.extra-long {
  height: 200vw;
}

nav.navbar-green {
  background-color: green;
}

nav.navbar-blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="extra-long">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <p>LOGO ABCD</p>
    <p>A</p>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code cleaned up that works. You'll have to change the color as needed:

```js
const w = $(window); 
const header = $('#main-header'); 
w.on('scroll', function() { 
  if(w.scrollTop() > 0) { 
    header.addClass('header-secondary'); 
  } else { 
    header.removeClass('header-secondary'); 
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 50px;
  transition: background-color ease .3s; 
}
header nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
header nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#logo {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.header-secondary {
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: #fff;
}
.header-secondary nav a {
  color: #fff;
}
main {
  padding: 65px 15px 0;
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 200%;
}
main p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header id="main-header">
  <p id="logo">LOGO ABCD</p>
  <nav>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
    <a href="">item</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis adipisci totam odit natus voluptates ducimus impedit provident eum quia asperiores vitae neque ullam deserunt enim dolore minima, cum, perferendis et laborum. Magni, odit. Ducimus reiciendis illo assumenda dignissimos? Quidem eligendi molestiae atque mollitia, exercitationem officia. Debitis incidunt voluptas explicabo aliquam.</p>
</main>
```